# Unable to delete item from redux store, payload is a long list of strings

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to delete an item from the store using useDispatch from redux. However the payload which is sent through via action is undefined.
Here is my reducer:

```
export const DELETE_ITEM = 'DELETE_ITEM';
    
case DELETE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter((item, item_code) => item_code !== payload),
      };
```

And Here is my action:

```
//delete items
export const deleteItemAction = (item_code) => {
  return {type: DELETE_ITEM, payload: item_code};
};
```

And Finally my function & component

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const delete_item = (item_code: any) => {
    dispatch(deleteItemAction({item_code: item_code}));
    console.log(item_code);
};

  <FlatList
       data={items}
       keyExtractor={items.item_code}
       renderItem={({item}) => (
         <View>
           <Text>{item.item_id}</Text>
           <Text>{item.item_type}</Text>
           <Text>{item.item_code}</Text>
           <Text>{item.item_description}</Text>
           <Text>{item.cost_price}</Text>
           <Text>{item.quantity}</Text>
           <Text>{item.selling_price}</Text>
          <View>
             <Button title="Delete" onPress={delete_item} />
              <Button title="Edit" onPress={() => {}} />
           </View>
       </View>
    )}
  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a temporary fix,

```
<Button title='Delete' onPress={() => {
   dispatch(deleteItemAction(item.item_code));
}}
```